# discord.js - give role by reacting - return value problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, chatbot

So I wanted a command intomy bot, which iis able to give server roles if you react on the message. By google/youtube I done this. My problem is, that if I react on the message my algorith won't step into my switch also if I react to the costum emoji it won't even detect it that I reacted for it. Probably somewhere the return value is different but I was unable to find it yet. Sy could check on it?

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const { config: { prefix } } = require('../app');

exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {

    await message.delete().catch(O_o=>{});

    const a = message.guild.roles.cache.get('697214498565652540'); //CSGO
    const b = message.guild.roles.cache.get('697124716636405800'); //R6
    const c = message.guild.roles.cache.get('697385382265749585'); //PUBG
    const d = message.guild.roles.cache.get('697214438402687009'); //TFT

    const filter = (reaction, user) => ['' , '' , '' , '<:tft:697426435161194586>' ].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;

    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Available Roles')
        .setDescription(`

         ${a.toString()}
         ${b.toString()}
         ${c.toString()}
        <:tft:697426435161194586> ${d.toString()}

        `)
        .setColor(0xdd9323)
        .setFooter(`ID: ${message.author.id}`);

    message.channel.send(embed).then(async msg => {

        await msg.react('');
        await msg.react('');
        await msg.react('');
        await msg.react('697426435161194586');

        msg.awaitReactions(filter, {
            max: 1,
            time: 15000,
            errors: ['time']
        }).then(collected => {

            const reaction = collected.cache.first();

            switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
                case '':
                    message.member.addRole(a).catch(err => {
                        console.log(err);
                        return message.channel.send(`Error adding you to this role **${err.message}.**`);
                    });
                    message.channel.send(`You have been added to the  **${a.name}** role!`).then(m => m.delete(30000));
                    msg.delete();
                    break;
                case '':
                    message.member.addRole(b).catch(err => {
                        console.log(err);
                        return message.channel.send(`Error adding you to this role **${err.message}.**`);
                    });
                    message.channel.send(`You have been added to the  **${b.name}** role!`).then(m => m.delete(30000));
                    msg.delete();
                    break;
                case '':
                    message.member.addRole(c).catch(err => {
                        console.log(err);
                        return message.channel.send(`Error adding you to this role **${err.message}.**`);
                    });
                    message.channel.send(`You have been added to the  **${c.name}** role!`).then(m => m.delete(30000));
                    msg.delete();
                    break;
                case '<:tft:697426435161194586>':
                    message.member.addRole(d).catch(err => {
                        console.log(err);
                        return message.channel.send(`Error adding you to this role **${err.message}.**`);
                    });
                    message.channel.send(`You have been added to the  **${d.name}** role!`).then(m => m.delete(30000));
                    msg.delete();
                    break;
            }
        }).catch(collected => {
            return message.channel.send(`I couldn't add you to this role!`);
        });
    });
};

exports.help = {
    name: 'roles'
};
```

Answer (score 2):

As of discord.js v12, the new way to add a role is `message.member.roles.add(role)`, not `message.member.addRole`. Refer to the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `roles.add()` instead of `addRole()`

Answer (score 0):

Mate, You cannot use the id of emoji in codes(except when you are sending a message). so, the custom emoji has to be replaced by a real emoji that shows a box in your editor and works perfectly in discord. If you can find it, then this might be complete as discord API cannot find the emoji <:tft:697426435161194586>. you can get an emoji by using it in discord and opening discord in a browser and through inspect element, get the emoji.

Else, you will have to use different emoji.